# angular promise then issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Playing around with angular resource i cant figure out why it works this way.
I have following code (let's assume that query function works fine):

```
$scope.getSomething = function (someObject) {
    var result;
    Factory.getSomething.query({ id: someObject.id }).$promise.then(function (success) {
        alert('success');
        result = 'success';
    },
    function(error) {
        alert('error');
        result = 'error';
    });
    alert(result);
};
```

When i execute this method i get following:
1) Alert with undefined
2) Alert with 'success'

Why undefined is first? As I understand $promise right, then

```
alert('success');
result = 'success';
```

should work first if succeed (when asynchronous is executed).
Then should be invoked last alert with `result` value.
But seems like it works not like i am expecting.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise means that while it's processing it allows other code to run. Therefore while your `getSomething` request is being processed on the server your browser is running the rest of the code, in this case the `alert(result)`.

At that point `result` hasn't yet been assigned so it's `undefined`. Then your web service returns, and the success code runs with runs the "success" `alert` which is the second alert message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are alerting `result` before it's defined, therefore you get an alert with `undefined`. `result` only gets a value after the async operation has been completed, either in your `then` or `error`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a particular reason that you need to deal with the raw $promise returned by $resource I find it a lot easier to just use the built in success/failure handlers.

```
Factory.getSomething.query({id: someObject.id}, function(data) {
    // this will be asynchronously called when the API call returns with success. data is your payload
}, function(error) {
    // this will be asynchronously called when the API call returns with error
});
```